# issue with TYPENAME(s) in KVP for WFS

Tags: wfs

I have this service: `http://sdi.gdos.gov.pl/wfs?SERVICE=WFS&REQUEST=GetCapabilities&VERSION=2.0.0` in version 2.0.0.

When I do a describe feature request for a certain feature type, the key to select the relevant feature type in the KVP should be TYPENAMES. TYPENAME is used for earlier versions.

For example: http://sdi.gdos.gov.pl/wfs?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=2.0.0&REQUEST=DescribeFeatureType&TYPENAMES=GDOS:SpecjalneObszaryOchrony should work, but it does not. It is not selecting only the feature type `GDOS:SpecjalneObszaryOchrony`.

But if I used http://sdi.gdos.gov.pl/wfs?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=2.0.0&REQUEST=DescribeFeatureType&TYPENAME=GDOS:SpecjalneObszaryOchrony with TYPENAME for earlier versions, then it works.

Why TYPENAMES does not work? I added the version in the KVP, so it should be fine!

Comment: Strictly you should use `acceptVERSIONs` instead of `VERSION` for a WFS 2 GetCapabilities request

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**

Despite my answer below was accepted with upvotes it is unfortunately wrong. I checked the WFS 2.0 standard:

```
Table 15 — DescribeFeatureType KVP encoding
TYPENAME - A comma separated list of feature types to describe. If no value is
specified, the complete application schema offered by the server
shall be described.
```

So you must use TYPENAMES in GetFeature but TYPENAME in DescribeFeatureType. The Polish server behaves correctly.

My answer was:

*Software do have bugs. This certain server does not behave according to WFS 2.0.0 standand with the DescribeCoverage request. It awaits "TYPENAME" as a keyword and when it sees "TYPENAMES" it skips the whole parameter as unknown and unsupported. You get the same response by keywords like &FOO= or &TYPNAM=
http://sdi.gdos.gov.pl/wfs?SERVICE=WFS&VERSION=2.0.0&REQUEST=DescribeFeatureType&TYPNAM=GDOS:SpecjalneObszaryOchrony*